# Web Api Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-webapi

I've an error: `"ExceptionMessage": "Self referencing loop detected for property 'Posto' with type 'UfficioServer.Posto'. Path '[0].Dipendente[0]'.",`

when i call my web api, i need a list of Posti whit the association with Dipendente...

```
 public List<Posto> GetAllPosti()
    {

        try
        {
            List<Posto> p = new List<Posto>();
            UfficioPostiEntities1 db = new UfficioPostiEntities1();
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            var posto = db.Posto.Include("Dipendente").ToList();
            var x = db.Posto.ToList();



            return x;
        }
```

can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To avoid this error you should add the following to the Application_Start in Global.asax:

```
HttpConfiguration config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;

config.Formatters.JsonFormatter
        .SerializerSettings
        .ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
```

This is because (as per documentation)

> **`ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore`**: Json.NET will ignore objects in
>   reference loops and not serialize them. **The first time an object is
>   encountered it will be serialized as usual but if the object is
>   encountered as a child object of itself the serializer will skip
>   serializing it.**